# How can I get last tuple in space?

Tags: tarantool

How can I get last tuple in space? Last tuple here is tuple with max primary key value

```
 local a = box.space.SPACE:len()
 box.space.SPACE:get{a}
```

This variant is not suitable because the number of tuples is not equal to the number of created indexes

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get last tuple in your case is `box.space.X.index[0]:max()`
or `box.space.X.index[0]:select({MAX_INT}, {limit=1, iterator='LE"})[1]`, if you prefer...